# Generate Javadoc for Talend user routines

Tags: java, javadoc, talend

I'm trying to generate documentation for some of the routines that I wrote in Talend (v7.3.1). I know there is a documentation generation tool within Talend, but it only works for jobs.

I have routines like this one:
[image]

That are described and everything, but I want to generate a documentation like for the jobs or javadoc.

Is there a way to achieve it with Talend?

Comment: I don't know Talend, but if this is a normal Java class, can't you just use the javadoc tool from Java?

Comment: Yes I know this is possible and I have done this before but it was more a question to find another solution for practicality because I have dozens of routines and doing it manually is a bit of a pain

Comment: Assuming you have it in some kind of project, you could use Maven, Gradle or even Ant to generate the javadoc over all classes.

Comment: Actually Talend does create a maven project structure, so you can use that to generate JavaDocs. But the structure is a bit weird, so you will probably generate docs for all stored versions in parallel.